# Как можно найти слова, которые даны во втором массиве в первом массиве

Tags: python, python-3.x

Например, у меня есть два txt-файла, один из них содержит текст

```
vlrtakeon
itredflow
ntuemturn
trgteaylp
arraysryi
gshjshhkg
etoesingg
```

а второй содержит

```
vintage
take
flow
remark
tea
array
toe
sing
turn
red
pig
```

Выступом будет массив, который содежит те элементы, которые не использовались для поиска слов.

Я открыл каждый файл и добавил их в два массива

```
with open("puzzle.txt") as f:
    puzzle = [list(line.strip()) for line in f]
with open("words.txt") as f:
    words = [list(line.strip()) for line in f]
```

Специально добавил текст в массив так, чтобы каждая буква была элементом массива, потому что ищу слова не только горизонтально, но еще вертикально и по диагонали.

Решил написать три функции, которые ищут слова горизонтально, вертикально и по диагонали.
И теперь не могу понять, как искать эти слова и считались буквы именно в этом порядке.
Знаю только как находить элементы, но слова - это же порядок букв а не один элемент.
Изначально думал удалять все слова, которые есть в первом массиве, но некоторые буквы используются по несколько раз.

Можете, пожалуйста, помочь хотя бы с поиском по вертикали, чтобы мог понять, как вы ищете эти слова в первом массиве.

Answer (score 1):

**Определим необходимые значения:**

```
elements = ['vlrtakeon',
         'itredflow',
         'ntuemturn',
         'trgteaylp',
         'arraysryi',
         'gshjshhkg',
         'etoesingg']

words = ['vintage'
          'take',
          'flow',
          'remark',
          'tea',
          'array',
          'toe',
          'sing',
          'turn',
          'red',
          'pig']
```

**Пример решения "по горизонтали":**

```
for word in words:
    for element in elements:
        if word in element:
            print(word, ' входит в ', element)
```

**Консоль:**

```
# flow входит в itredflow
# tea входит в trgteaylp
# array входит в arraysryi
# toe входит в etoesingg
# sing входит в etoesingg
# turn входит в ntuemturn
# red входит в itredflow
```

**Пример решения "по вертикали":**

```
verical_words = [] # Создадим массив для слов по вертикали
every_element_len = 9  # Зададим значение для длины каждого слова
for i in range (0, every_element_len): # Пройдемся циклом от 0 до заданной длины каждого слова
    vertical_word = [] # Создадим массив для каждого знака вертикального слова
    for element in elements: # Пройдемся циклом по всем элементам 
        vertical_word.append(element[i]) # Наполним массив для каждого знака значениями

    verical_words.append(''.join(vertical_word)) # Конвертируем знаки в строковые значения

# Выполним поиск (смысл vertical_word заменится):
for word in words: 
    for vertical_word in verical_words:
        if word in vertical_word:
            print(word, ' входит в ', vertical_word)
```

**Консоль:**

```
# vintage  входит в  vintage
# pig  входит в  nwnpigg
```

Comment: спасибо, но это я знаю как, прикол в том, что у меня массив двумерный, т.е у меня первый ряд массива состоит из элементов ['v','l','r','t','a','k','e','o','n'] дальше второй ряд массива и т.д. Второй txt файл я открыл тоже как двумерный массив. Из-за этого, на самом деле, надо считать порядок этих элементов. Потому что этот метод не может найти слова, расположенные вертикально или по диагонали

Comment: @Khimer дополнил решением по вертикали, диагональ будет иметь схожую логику перебора.
Из условия я понял, что перевод массива в двумерный вид - опциональное условие, поэтому не использовал его, чтобы не усложнять конструкцию, но схожее решение можно применить и для двумерного массива. Мне в решении помогло сначала расписать простыми словами, что я хочу получить в итоге, а только потом приводить это к коду.

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = [[]] 
list2 = []
# Поиск по горизонтали
for i in range(len(list1)):
    for word in list2:
        if word in ''.join(list1[i]):
            print(f'Word {word} in {list1[i]}')
vertical_words = []
word = ''
# Составляем массив со словами по вертикали
for i in range(len(list1[0]))
    for j in range(len(list1)):
        word += list1[j][i]
    vertical_words.append(word)
    word = ''
# Поиск по вертикали
for ver_word in vertical_words:
    for word in list2:
        if word in ver_word:
            print(f'Word {word} in {ver_word}')
# Поиск слов по диагонали
gor_words = []
gor_word = ''
for i in range(len(list1[0])):
    x = i
    y = 0
    while x < len(list1[x]) and y < len(list1)
        gor_word += list1[y][x]
        x += 1
        y += 1
    gor_words.append(gor_word)
    gor_word = ''
for i in range(len(list1)):
    x = i
    y = 0
    while y < len(list1[x]) and x < len(list1)
        gor_word += list1[x][y]
        x += 1
        y += 1
    gor_words.append(gor_word)
    gor_word = ''
for goriz_word in gor_words:
    for word in list2:
        if word in goriz_word:
            print(f'Word {word} in {goriz_word}')
```

Этот алгоритм поиска не очень быстрый
Для поиска по горизонтали O(n*m), где n(длина list1) m(длина list2)
Для поиска по вертикали O(n*m+i*k), где n(длина list1[0]) m(длина list1) k(длина list2) i(длина vertical_words)

Comment: у меня задача просто заключалась в другом. все эти слова со второго массива, нужно убрать с первого массива и там в конце останутся те буквы, к которым мы не прикасались, но просто удалять эти слова со второго массива не получится, потому что некоторые буквы используются по несколько раз, вот и думал, что лучше будет работать с двумерными массивами, но спасибо за ответ

Comment: @Тогда могу посоветовать все же создать еще один массив простой и использовать функцию str.find(str_in). Он возвращает индекс с которого начинается str_in в str если его там нет то возвращает -1. Ты с помощью этой функции получаешь индекс начала str_in и с for до длины str_in начиная с этого индекса удаляешь элементы массивы из puzzle

Comment: вроде бы понял, только получится ли так посчитать по всем диагоналям?

Comment: @Khimer вот добавил поиск по диагонали проверьте его и если правильно, отметьте мой ответ правильным